# Uno-Flip going out on a flip

Tags: uno-flip

If you go out playing a flip card does the cards flip and those points calculated? Example final card is a light flip.. does the cards change to dark and those points calculates

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The card is played as normal. (Just like in regular Uno, in order to go out, you have to play your last card. A card played is resolved when played, whether it is the final card play or not.)